# In a Struts Action, can I write out a byte array as well as redirect the page? (Struts 1, Java)

Tags: java, apache, jsp, struts, struts-1

I'm working on a project in which, after the user submits a form, I'd like to have them download a PDF file (filled out with information from the form) as well as redirect them to another page. I know how to redirect (returning an `ActionForward` which is set up to redirect to the correct JSP) and I know how to send the PDF (I build it using iText library, then write the byte array out to the `HttpServletResponse`'s output stream), but I'm not sure how to do both without some sort of kludge.

I'm guessing I'll have to do one of the two using javascript/ajax, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this with struts.

Comment: Those are 2 different requests. Regardless of the framework doing all this, you can't download a file and a see a page with the same request. (Technically, you could with a multipart response, but I don't think browsers are setup for this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with servlets.

What I end up doing in these situations is request the file with a timestamp as a request parameter.

When I write the response I set a cookie with that timestamp.  Every few moments on the client side I check to see if that cookie exists, if it does, I window.location to the 'redirect' page.